# Do we flag answers which offer nothing new

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging

I know we can mark duplicate posts but, what if the answer is a duplicate because it's a combination of different answers (all from the answers on the same post)? Are we still to flag it?

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9256/how-do-we-handle-duplicate-answers http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2641/should-duplicate-answers-posted-within-a-short-time-frame-be-flagged

Comment: @random, I'm not sure why this is a dupe. My question isn't about what happens if a duplicate SINGLE answer is posted, more about what happens if an answer only contains information found in a COMBINATION of the posts ... Both posts you cite explain a post is a copy of a SINGLE post. Unless I missed something (or maybe my post wasn't clear)?

Comment: Depends on how they present the information, but if it's just a bare collection, it's the same as a single component answer

Comment: You've just explained that the answer is the same - that doesn't mean the question is! But I'll leave it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we do.

Flag for moderator attention with a free-text flag as "duplicate answer" or similiar. For more information, see [What is the policy on duplicate answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5061/what-is-the-policy-on-duplicate-answers)

Comment: Just for clarity though, this is also true if the answer is a duplicate because it's made up of multiple answers?

Comment: In my opinion, because it still contributes nothing new to the question, it should still be flagged.

Comment: It's helpful to also point out the specific answers that are being duplicated in the free text of the flag.